# Generate SAML OAM metadata that works with asp.net web forms project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, oam

I am trying to configure a web application using ASP.NET for Single-SignOn with OAM based system.

To configure their OAM, my client asked me to provide a SAML Service Provider metadata file matching the following format:

I need to understand how do I generate entity ID & AssertionConsumerServiceLocation. I also need to know whether this metadata file will be generates in visual studio or by OAM

[image]